# NHibernate Unique Constraint on Name and Parent Object fails because NH inserts Null

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an object as follows

```
Public Class Bin

  Public Property Id As Integer

  Public Property Name As String

  Public Property Store As Store

End Class

Public Class Store

    Public Property Id As Integer

    Public Property Bins As IEnumerable(Of Bin)

End Class
```

I have a unique constraint in the database on Bin.Name and BinStoreID to ensure unique names within stores. However, when NHibernate persists the store, it first inserts the Bin records with a null StoreID before performing an update later to set the correct StoreID. This violates the Unique Key If I persist two stores with a Bin of the same name because The Name columns are the same and the StoreID is null for both.

Is there something I can add to the mapping to ensure that the correct StoreID is included in the INSERT rather than performing an update later? We are using HiLo identity generation so we are not relying on DB generated identity columns

EDIT:
Mapping information for the store on the bin type is

```
<many-to-one class="NHS.EDC.SM.Data.Entities.Store, EDCBusinessLogic.SM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Store">
  <column name="StoreID" unique-key="UniqueBinKey" />
</many-to-one>
```

And for the bins on the store is

```
<set access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="Bins" mutable="true">
  <key>
    <column name="StoreID" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="NHS.EDC.SM.Data.Entities.Bin, EDCBusinessLogic.SM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</set>
```

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

You must map the `Bins` collection as inverse and cascading, and always set both sides of the relationship (add to the collection, and set `Bin.Store`.

This is described in [6.4. One-To-Many Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-onetomany) and  [6.8. Bidirectional Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-bidirectional)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added the mapping which I am using to the post but I think it's correct based on what you've said?

Comment: The mapping looks correct... I was going to ask if you were setting both sides, but then I saw your answer to Jamie Ide, so I believe you are.

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: @user3270407 fixed

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code that is saving the Bin object. If you are doing it in this order:

```
session.Save(myBin);
bin.Store = myStore;
session.Flush();
```

NHibernate will generate an insert using the state of the object at the time `Save` was called and an update when `Flush` is called. Setting the Store property before flushing the session will correct this.

Comment: Yes, the object hierarchy is constructed first (with the appropriate backreferences) and then onyl the aggregate root (store) is saved